# "is started to be" or "starts to be" which is grammatically correct?

Tags: passive-voice

> When I started turning the steering wheel, it emitted a strange sound.

I am trying to rewrite the above sentence such that the steering wheel is the subject. I would like to know which of the following is correct.

> 1. The steering wheel emitted a strange sound when it **was started to be**
>      turn.
> 2. The steering wheel emitted a strange sound when it **started to
>          be** turned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first sentence is not correct: you should not use passive voice for start in this context, because the main activity is turning, not starting. It is optional for turn:

> The steering wheel emitted a strange sound when it started to turn.
>   The steering wheel emitted a strange sound when it started turning.
>   The steering wheel emitted a strange sound when it started to be turned.

The first two versions might give the impression that the wheel turned on its own: the second version sounds over-complex.

It would make a more natural sentence if you kept the steering wheel as the subject of the first clause, but made it the object of the second clause:

> The steering wheel emitted a strange sound when I started to turn it.

**emit** is a bit technical: **make** would work better in informal spoken English.

Comment: How about "at the start of turn of it"?

Comment: Nope, There's a **the** missing, it's not natural, and **turn of it** sounds like you are talking about its turn in a game. The first two of my suggestions would be better.

Comment: @JavaLatte, is it not a bit sweeping to say never use the passive voice with start? "When the Lottery was started it was not popular." In that example passive is OK grammatically and if the point being  made is about the early popularity of the Lottery we don't need to know who did the starting.

Comment: @JeremyC: I only meant in this context, where **start** affects another verb: in such cases, it's the other verb that should be passivized. "This area was nice until students started to occupy it" -> "This area was nice until it started to be occupied by students". By all means, use start in passive voice when starting is the only activity.